# Python: Not able to slice string

Tags: python

I am trying to make one program using python where User has to put value which is equal to any name or any word and what it does is that it cut first letter of the word and paste it at the end of the word and adds 2 more alphabet equal to 'py'.

---

Ex- Enter the value: Shashank
'Output which i am getting is shashankspy' but the value which I want is 'hashankspy'

The code which i made is this:

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original

    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word + first + pyg
    new_word[1:]


else:
    print 'empty'
```

I am not able to get the real value. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one simple error which you are making and it can be done as:

```
new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]

    pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original

    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word + first + pyg
    new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]


else:
    print 'empty'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to stake a slice from the word `[1:]`:

```
new_word = word[1:] + first + pyg
```

Also, instead of checking the length for being more than zero, just check for emptiness:

```
if original and original.isalpha():
```

Demo:

```
>>> def make_new_word(s):
...     pyg = 'py'
...     if s and s.isalpha():
...         word = s.lower()
...         first = word[0]
...         new_word = word[1:] + first + pyg
...         return new_word
...     else:
...         return 'empty' 
... 
>>> original = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
Enter a word: Shashank
>>> make_new_word(original)
'hashankspy'
```

Comment: Well thanks your answer is correct but what's the problem i am facing when i type this code                                                 new_word = word + first + pyg
 new_word[1:]

Comment: @ShashankSharma you just don't print it.

Comment: Ya I know i didn't mention here but i have putted that syntax ... but after typing new_word[1:] and print new_word why i cant get the real value as true.

Comment: @ShashankSharma you needed to just `print new_word[1:]`.

Comment: `new_word[1:]`, by itself, does not print anything and does not change `new_word`. It simply computes that slice, and then throws it away since you haven't specified anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The minute you put in a space, original.isalpha() becomes false because a space is not A-Z.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like adding

new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]

---

```
pyg = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a word:')

if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    print original

    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    new_word = word + first + pyg
    new_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)]


else:
    print 'empty'
```